# MySQL Query: Epoch Time Filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I am having issues with my php script. I was wondering whether anyone knows how to set-up a filter when doing a MySQL query. My current query is the following:

`SELECT * FROM places WHERE location = '".$_REQUEST['placename']."' AND date > 1320968873`

As you can see the location is requested by the user but considering the amount of data collected and entered with Unix time stamps. I would like to further enhance the query by altering the date section so that it auto-completes with a time stamp of a roughly 30 seconds before the query is being asked.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Be a shame if someone trashed your server with it.

Comment: How would I avoid something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30`?

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From locations WHERE location = :place_name AND date > FROM_UNIXTIME(:current_time - 30)
```

Where :place_name and :current_time are variables passed from your php script (:current_time would be in 'Unix Time' format assuming that the date column is a DATETIME type.)